# How to read lines in an output (generated using command) after a certain string?

Tags: python-3.x, popen

I have to run the UNIX specific command using python and capture only the line after "Test Failed: " line.
The approach I used is:

```
import os
def system_check(command: str):
    stream = os.popen(command)
    output = stream.readlines()
    for line in output:
        if line.strip().startswith('Test Failed: '):
            for line in output:
                print(line)
```

This reads every line starting from the beginning, not only after "Test Failed". If I use file reading as in [How to only read lines in a text file after a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805919) 
it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution to that question is correct since the user wants all lines after a specific string.

To your question, however, you try this, without using another loop:

```
for line_nr, line in enumerate(output):
        if line.startswith('Test Failed: '):
            print(output[line_nr+1])
```

Or:

```
`for line_nr, line in enumerate(output):
   if 'Test Failed: ' in line:
     print(output[line_nr+1])`
```

On a second note, to why does it print all lines (event those that are before 'Test Failed: ') perhaps it might had to do it with the `strip()` method and the content of the output.

Comment: This doesn't work! It only prints one line next to line starting with 'Test Failed:'

Comment: @gdi, make some edits; let me know if still doesn t wor