# Pattern searching in a file and replacing the found results

Tags: python, regex, file, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simple program that will open text files in given directory search for all strings that match a given pattern and replace them with the desired string while removing all other info. I have two .txt files:

User_321.txt which contains:

```
321_AliceKelly001.jpg [size_info] [date_info] [geo_location_info] ... [other info]
321_AliceKelly002.jpg [size_info] [date_info] [geo_location_info] ... [other info] 
321_AliceKelly003.jpg [size_info] [date_info] [geo_location_info] ... [other info]
 ...
321_AliceKelly125.jpg [size_info] [date_info] [geo_location_info] ... [other info]
```

and User_205.txt which contains:

```
 205_CarlCarlson001.jpg [size_info] [date_info] [geo_location_info] ... [other info]
 205_CarlCarlson002.jpg [size_info] [date_info] [geo_location_info] ... [other info]
 205_CarlCarlson_003.jpg [size_info] [date_info] [geo_location_info] ... [other info]
 205_CarlCarlson007.jpg [size_info] [date_info] [geo_location_info] ... [other info]
```

I want User_321.txt to contain:

```
321_AliceKelly_001.jpg
321_AliceKelly_002.jpg 
321_AliceKelly_003.jpg
 ...
321_AliceKelly_125.jpg
```

and User_205.txt to contain:

```
 205_CarlCarlson_001.jpg
 205_CarlCarlson_002.jpg
 205_CarlCarlson_003.jpg
 205_CarlCarlson_007.jpg
```

So I simply want to add "_" between the name and last 3 digits. I'm able to handle the case where all the entries are uniform, that is only contain entries of the following form:

```
     \d\d\d_[a-zA-Z]\d\d\d.jpg [size_info] [date_info] [geo_location_info] ... [other info]
```

with the following code:

```
import os, re,

path = 'C:\\Users\\ME\\Desktop\\TEST'
text_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir(path)]

desired_text = re.compile(r'\w+.jpg')
#desired_ending = re.compile(r'$[a-zA-Z]\d\d\d.jpg')

for i in range(len(text_files)):
    working_file = path + '\\' + text_files[i]
    fin = open(working_file, 'r')
    match = ''

    for line in fin:
        mo1 = desired_text.search(line)
        if mo1 != '':
            match += mo1.group()[:-7] + '_' + mo1.group()[-7:]+'\n'

    fin.close()

    fout = open(working_file, 'w')
    fout.write(match)
    fout.close()
```

I'm having a difficult time with the second case, that is when I have an entry that is already in the desired form, like with:

```
 205_CarlCarlson_003.jpg [size_info] [date_info] [geo_location_info] ... [other info]
 205_CarlCarlson007.jpg [size_info] [date_info] [geo_location_info] ... [other info].
```

I would like for it to skip renaming the entry that is already in the desired form and continue with the rest.

I've had a look at [How to search and replace text in a file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-python) and [Cheap way to search a large text file for a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893885/cheap-way-to-search-a-large-text-file-for-a-string), and [Search and replace a line in a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python). These cases seem to be concerned with searching for a specific string and replacing it with another using the fileinput module. I would like to do something similar but be a little more flexible in its search.

Comment: Replace the `desired_text` regex with `r'^\s*\d{3}_[^\W_]+\.jpg'`. If there is a match, add a `_`. If there is no match, the `_` must be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly modificated your code, handling the two different cases, and it seems to work:

```
import os, re

path = 'C:\\Users\\ME\\Desktop\\TEST'
text_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir(path)]

desired_text1 = re.compile(r'^\d{3}_[a-zA-Z]+\d{3}.jpg')
desired_text2 = re.compile(r'^\d{3}_[a-zA-Z]+_\d{3}.jpg')

for i in range(len(text_files)):
    working_file = path + '\\' + text_files[i]
    fin = open(working_file, 'r')
    match = ''

    for line in fin:
        mo1 = desired_text1.search(line)
        mo2 = desired_text2.search(line)
        if mo1:
            match += mo1.group()[:-7] + '_' + mo1.group()[-7:]+'\n'
        elif mo2:
            match += mo2.group() +'\n'

    fin.close()

    fout = open(working_file, 'w')
    fout.write(match)
    fout.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parentheses for grouping and capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

```
\b(\d{3}_[a-zA-Z]+)(\d{3}\.jpg)
```

and replace with `\1_\2` to add an underscore in between.

- `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- Rest like your sample form, separated in two groups.

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hI9cB4/2) (Python code generator)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
with open('source.txt') as f:
    with open('destination.txt', 'w') as g:
        for line in f:
            parts = line.split(None, 1)
            if parts[0][-8:-7] == '_':
                g.write(parts[0] + '\n')
            else:
                g.write(parts[0][:-7] + '_' + parts[0][-7:] + '\n')
```

Feel free to change `\n` to `\r\n` if you want a Windows newline sequence.