# Reading a file until a specific character in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on an application which requires reading all the input from a file until a certain character is encountered.

By using the code:

```
file=open("Questions.txt",'r')
c=file.readlines()
c=[x.strip() for x in c]
```

Every time strip encounters `\n`, it is removed from the input and treated as a string in list `c`.

This means every line is split into the part of a list `c`. But **I want to make a list up to a point whenever a special character is encountered** like this:

if the input file has the contents:

```
1.Hai
2.Bye\-1
3.Hello
4.OAPd\-1
```

then I want to get a list as
`c=['1.Hai\n2.Bye','3.Hello\n4.OApd']`

Please help me in doing this.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980776/python-readline-with-custom-delimiter | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893885/cheap-way-to-search-a-large-text-file-for-a-string

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The easiest way would be to read the file in as a single string and then split it across your separator:

```
with open('myFileName') as myFile:
  text = myFile.read()
result = text.split(separator)  # use your \-1 (whatever that means) here
```

In case your file is very large, holding the complete contents in memory as a single string for using `.split()` is maybe not desirable (and then holding the complete contents in the list after the split is probably also not desirable).  Then you could read it in chunks:

```
def each_chunk(stream, separator):
  buffer = ''
  while True:  # until EOF
    chunk = stream.read(CHUNK_SIZE)  # I propose 4096 or so
    if not chunk:  # EOF?
      yield buffer
      break
    buffer += chunk
    while True:  # until no separator is found
      try:
        part, buffer = buffer.split(separator, 1)
      except ValueError:
        break
      else:
        yield part

with open('myFileName') as myFile:
  for chunk in each_chunk(myFile, separator='\\-1\n'):
    print(chunk)  # not holding in memory, but printing chunk by chunk
```

Comment: Using [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) instead of [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) might be faster.

Answer (score -3):

I used "*" instead of "-1", I'll let you make the appropriate changes.

```
s = '1.Hai\n2.Bye*3.Hello\n4.OAPd*'
temp = ''
results = []

for char in s:
    if char is '*':
        results.append(temp)
        temp = []
    else:
        temp += char

if len(temp) > 0:
    results.append(temp)
```

Comment: -1 because it doesn't work. I got `['1.Hai\n2.Bye', ['3', '.', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\n', '4', '.', 'O', 'A', 'P', 'd']]`. `temp = []` should be replaced with `temp = ''`. Also `char is '*'` ?! Since when strings are compared with `is` instead of `==`?