# Quickest way of checking if a csv column consists of a particular value in python

Tags: python, csv

What is the quickest way to get the row that contains the column having a particular value 'X'. For example, if I have a csv having the following columns :

```
item_no.,item_Name,item_price
```

What is the best way (in terms of execution time) to get the record having item_name = 'X'? I know we can iterate over the whole csv to get this, but it seems expensive in terms of execution time.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: if you want to search several times, you can iterate once and create a dictionary wih item name as key and the rest as values (if item name is unique). But you can't possibly search data without iterating on it at least once...

Comment: Is the .csv file sorted by item_name? If yes, you can use binary search. Otherwise, you must iterate row by row.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes I did think of that but I was just wondering if there was any library that could perform the task at a low level, and hence save time.

Comment: @AndrejKesely no it isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast file search/find of text

Optimizations

- Process file in binary (removes the overhead of binary to text conversions)
- Search a buffer at a time rather than line by line
- Convert found line from binary to text

**Code**

[Inspired by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893885/cheap-way-to-search-a-large-text-file-for-a-string/57133315#57133315)

```
def find_line(fname, goal):
    " Generator of lines containing goal string "

    def str_to_bytes(s):
        ' String to byte array '
        result = bytearray()
        result.extend(map(ord, s))
        return result

    def find_buffer(fname, goal, start=0, bsize=2**17):
        """
            Processing file in binary to find goal string
                - removes overhead of binary to text conversions
            Uses find method on a buffer of data at a time
                - faster than check each line by line
        """
        bgoal = str_to_bytes(goal)            # convert goal string to binary
        bnew_line = str_to_bytes(os.linesep)  # line separator as byte array

        if bsize < len(bgoal):
            raise ValueError("The buffer size must be larger than the string being searched for.")
        with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
            if start > 0:
                f.seek(start)
            overlap = len(bgoal) - 1
            while True:
                buffer = f.read(bsize)
                pos = buffer.find(bgoal)

                if pos >= 0:
                    start_line = buffer.rfind(bnew_line, 0, pos)
                    end_line = buffer.find(bnew_line, pos)
                    yield buffer[start_line+len(bnew_line):end_line] #f.tell() - len(buffer) + pos
                if not buffer:
                    return None
                f.seek(f.tell() - overlap)

    # Find line in file
    os_encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
    delimiter = str_to_bytes(',')  # column delimiter in bytes
    bgoal = str_to_bytes(goal)

    for line in find_buffer(fname, goal):
        # convert to text
        # Insure it's in 2nd column
        columns = line.split(str_to_bytes(','))
        if columns[1] == bgoal:
            return line.decode(os_encoding)

    else:
        return None
```

**Usage**

```
line = find_buffer_method(filename, search_string)
```

**Performance Testing**

Generate 1M row text file similar to posters format

*File Generation Code*

[Inspired by](https://gist.github.com/AlanHohn/293c98f9dadfc67443b8078d843d4401)

Create CSV file with 1 million rows

```
import csv
import random

records= 100000   # number of rows to generate
print("Making %d records\n" % records)

fieldnames = ['item_no.','item_Name','item_price']

with open("data.csv", "w", newline='') as my_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(my_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for i in range(records):
        writer.writerow(
            {
                'item_no.': i,
                'item_Name': "X{}".format(i),
                'item_price': random.randint(1, 100)
            })
```

*Line by Line Method (to provide a speed baseline)*

```
def line_by_line(fname, goal):
   " Line by line search for goal string "
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if goal in line:
                # Insure found in 2nd column
                columns = line.split(',')
                if columns[1] == goal:
                    return line
        return None
```

Timing using [Timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)

```
# Rows           find_line_method                 find_buffer_method          Speed Up
10,000           2.99 ms (7 runs/100 loops)       295 µs (7 runs/1000 loops)     10X
100,000         30.40 ms (7 runs/10 loops)        1.78 ms (7 runs/1000 loops)    17X
1M             321.00 ms (7 runs/1 loop)          19.7 ms (7 runs/10 loops)      17X
```

We note that the buffer is ~17X faster for larger files.

Note: Row in the table above is based upon what row the goal string is located in the 1M row file for the test.