# How to find multiple patterns from one text file and check each against a large file to find duplication?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two files, let's say File A and B. And I want to get a specific value after the word "Query" in File A and find that value in File B, which is a large file. After which if it matches, the python program will print "Sorry, item already exist".

One caveat is that File B is exported from a platform, so gibberish/additional data will be present.

An example of the files can be seen as shown below:

**File A:**

```
{"ID": "01", "Name": "..", "Query": "zzzzzzzzzzz"}{"ID": "02","Name": "..", "Query": "xxxaaaaxxxx"}
```

**File B**

```
[_some fileheader info]{"ID": "...", "Name": "..", "Query": "kkkkkkkkkk"}{"ID": "...", "Name": "..", "Query": "xxxxxxxxx" }{"ID": "...", "Name": "..", "Query": "zzzzzzzzzzz"}{"ID": "...", "Name": "..", "Query": "pppppppppp"}
```

So the expected outcome will be printed - "*Entry ID 01 already exist in File B!"*

This is what I am working on (am unsure how to specifically search for "Query"), but doesn't seem to work:

```py
    with open('FileA') as f1:
        with open('FileB') as f2:
              if f1.read() in f2.read():
                 print("Entry already exist!")
              else:
                 print("Importing entry....")
```

Comment: So you need to match _each_ `"Query": "<pattern>"` from FileA _anywhere_ in FileB? The order and the surrounding texts doesn't matter?

Comment: @GinoMempin Yes! That's what I am trying to achieve. And yes, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Does FileA follow any specific format? Based on your example, it doesn't look like JSON, and I think the trickier part here is parsing all the `"Query": "<pattern>"` and putting them all into a list. Once they're all on a list, then it's just a matter of applying existing solutions to [find a text in a large file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3893885/2745495).

Comment: @GinoMempin oh, its in ndjson file format. Will this make things trickier to put in a list?

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('FileA') as f1:
    with open('FileB') as f2:
        for i in f1.readline().split():
            for b in f2.readline().split():
                if i in b:
                    print('Yes')
                    break
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.